# Python chat p2p system over internet

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I want to build a peer to peer chat engine that runs over the Internet.  So far my code works on a local network but not further.  This is due to the fact that listening on sockets using python `sockets` does not make them available outside of the LAN.

It is acceptable for IPs to be shared knowledge, ie it is ok for the other person to need to know my IP address (and a port on which I am listening) to connect to me.

How does one tell the router to open a socket to the outside world?  Presumably this can be done as p2p software such as BitTorrent must do it for communication between clients.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned you have to open a specific port on the router and use that port for communication. As there are many router manufacturers each with a variety of models I suggest you to check the manual for the router you want to use.
for the code, you may check if your code works on LAN and then see if the router let's you white-list some ports. you may find many simple examples online.
this is a code i played sometime ago:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/vef4q4prkr7be2e/python.socket.zip

if you don't want users to mess up with ports and router settings and such, first alternative i can think of is this:

you setup an REST API, in one interface one is able to retrieve the messages providing (chatRoomName, FromTimestamp, ToTimestamp[,optionally chatRoomPassWord]) but this has nothing to do with sockets, you have to use simple HTTP requests(urllib/urllib2). Of course there might exist some workaround for this such as an always-white-listed port(like 80 for browsers, 22 for SSH) but you have to search for such exceptions.
note that ports up to 1024 require special privileges(admin/sudo) to be used.

p.s. in  traditional implementation other party(client) have to know your (ip, port) duo to be able to connect to the you(server).

Comment: Is it possible to do this automatically?  Say I wish to distribute the code; not all users would want to/be able to manually set up port forwarding on their router.

Comment: yeah, i am updating the post in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

An other alternative is gRPC protocol